# SQL Calculate records of a group then append the result in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
tbl_Trans
--------------------------------
|Instrument|Trans_Type|Quantity|
|----------+----------+--------|
|HFT 123   |DEB       |50000   |
|HFT 123   |DEB       |20000   | 
|HFT 123   |CRE       |10000   | 
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |40000   |
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |30000   |
--------------------------------
```

Then, I have to get the total Quantity of an Instrument based on the Trans_Type column. **DEB** means add and **CRE** means Subtract.

```
Example:
For HFT 123, Quantity=50000+20000-10000
             Quantity=60000
```

Then, the Total quantity should be appended in the table using **RES** in Trans_Type column. 
Final table should look like this:

```
--------------------------------
|Instrument|Trans_Type|Quantity|
|----------+----------+--------|
|HFT 123   |DEB       |50000   |
|HFT 123   |DEB       |20000   | 
|HFT 123   |CRE       |10000   | 
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |40000   |
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |30000   |
|HFT 123   |RES       |60000   |
|ZGS 425   |RES       |70000   |
--------------------------------
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH CTE
AS 
(
  SELECT Instrument,
  Trans_Type,
  CASE WHEN Trans_Type = 'DEB' THEN Quantity ELSE Quantity * -1 END AS Quantity
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT Instrument, Trans_type, Quantity FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Instrument, 'RES',
  SUM(Quantity) AS Total
FROM CTE AS c
GROUP BY Instrument
```

[**Try it your self here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d55a17/8)

This will give you what you need:

```
| Instrument | Trans_type | Quantity |
|------------|------------|----------|
|    HFT 123 |        DEB |    50000 |
|    HFT 123 |        DEB |    20000 |
|    HFT 123 |        CRE |    10000 |
|    ZGS 425 |        DEB |    40000 |
|    ZGS 425 |        DEB |    30000 |
|    HFT 123 |        RES |    60000 |
|    ZGS 425 |        RES |    70000 |
```

Comment: Clever. Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the totals using a grouped select, and append to the table the result of that select.

That would be :

```
insert into tbl_Trans (Instrument, Trans_Type, Quantity)
       select Instrument, 'RES', 
              sum(case Trans_Type when 'DEB' then Quantity 
                                  when 'CRE' then - 1 * Quantity)
       from tbl_Trans
       where Trans_Type in ('DEB', 'CRE')
       group by Instrument
```

The Table will now have the desired content :

```
|Instrument|Trans_Type|Quantity|
--------------------------------
|HFT 123   |DEB       |50000   |
|HFT 123   |DEB       |20000   | 
|HFT 123   |CRE       |10000   | 
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |40000   |
|ZGS 425   |DEB       |30000   |
|HFT 123   |RES       |60000   |
|ZGS 425   |RES       |70000   |
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL Server

**--To get the Total Quantity of an Instrument based on the Trans_Type**

SELECT Instrument,
       SUM(IIF(Trans_Type = 'CRE',-1*Quantity,Quantity)) AS [Total Quantity] 
FROM tbl_Trans WHERE Trans_Type IN ('DEB','CRE') 
GROUP BY Instrument

**--To append the Total quantity in the table**

INSERT INTO tbl_Trans (Instrument,Trans_Type,Quantity)
SELECT Instrument,
       'RES' AS [Trans_Type],
       SUM(IIF(Trans_Type = 'CRE',-1*Quantity,Quantity)) AS [Quantity] 
FROM tbl_Trans 
WHERE Trans_Type IN ('DEB','CRE') 
GROUP BY Instrument

[Try in fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7f18/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table  InstrumentTable  ( Instrument varchar(10) , Trans_Type char(3) ,  Quantity int)
go

insert into InstrumentTable
select 'HFT 123'   ,'DEB'       ,50000  
union all select 'HFT 123'   ,'DEB'       ,20000   
union all select 'HFT 123'   ,'CRE'       ,10000   
union all select 'ZGS 425'   ,'DEB'       ,40000    
union all select 'ZGS 425'   ,'DEB'       ,30000   

select Instrument  , Trans_Type  , Quantity from InstrumentTable
union all 
select Instrument  , 'RES'  ,  sum ( case when Trans_Type = 'DEB' then 
Quantity else (Quantity*-1) end )   
from InstrumentTable 
group by Instrument 
order by 1 ,2
```